# AlphaTestEffect.Projection property

Tags: c#, xna, render, target

I'm looking over this tutorial to mix different textures based on the types of pixels I want to pass:
http://www.crappycoding.com/tag/xna/page/2/

and so far I hink I understand the whole concept, except for couple lines in creating the AlphaTestEffect object, as there is very little explanation to it given and I have no clue what it is there for and why it's set up like that.

```
Matrix projection = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0, PlanetDataSize, PlanetDataSize, 0, 0, 1);
Matrix halfPixelOffset = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0);

alphaTestEffect.Projection = halfPixelOffset * projection;
```

Could somebody please explain these necesities, what they do and what they are for? I hope it won't take too much time, and my question is not a silly one.

cheers
Lucas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because he is using a custom effect instead of the default SpriteBatch one, he has to make sure the projection works the same way as the default (or rather, he's making it the same to make everything play nice together).

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/05/spritebatch-and-custom-shaders-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx

It's explained there if you scroll down a bit:

" This code configures BasicEffect to replicate the default SpriteBatch coordinate system:"

The default SpriteBatch camera is a simple orthographic projection with a half pixel offset to display 2D textures better. That can be explained here:

http://drilian.com/2008/11/25/understanding-half-pixel-and-half-texel-offsets/